# Using spring MVC in RAD 8.0 and Websphere 8.0

Tags: spring-mvc, ibm-rad

I get this error when I try to run a simple hello world application.
Any ideas as to what this error is?

org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet was found, but is missing another required class. SRVE0206E: This error typically implies that the servlet was originally compiled with classes which cannot be located by the server. SRVE0187E: Check your class path to ensure that all classes required by the servlet are present.SRVE0210I: This problem can be debugged by recompiling the servlet using only the classes in the application's runtime class path SRVE0234I: Application class path=[G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\lib;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\lib\dt.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\lib\htmlconverter.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\lib\ibmorbtools.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\lib\jconsole.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\lib\tools.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\classes;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\classes;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\EJBCommandTarget.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\IVTClient.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\OTiSConvertTime.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\activation-impl.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\admin.config.sched.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\aspectjrt.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\batch.wccm.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\batchprops.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\batchutilsfep.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\batfepapi.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\bootstrap.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\bsf-engines.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\commandlineutils.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\commons-discovery.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\databeans.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\ffdcSupport.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\htmlshell.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\iscdeploy.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\ivblogbr.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\j2ee.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\jNative2ascii.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\jacl.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\jrom.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\launchclient.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\lmproxy.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\mail-impl.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\openwebbeans.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\pc-appext.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\pmirm4arm.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\rrd-appext.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\rsadbutils.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\rsahelpers.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\serviceadapter.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\setup.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\startup.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\tcljava.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\urlprotocols.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\wasservicecmd.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\wses_dynaedge.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\wsif-compatb.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedChannels;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\web\help;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\deploytool\itp\plugins\com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy\runtime;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\deploytool\itp\plugins\com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy\runtime\batch.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\deploytool\itp\plugins\com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy\runtime\ejbdeploy.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\deploytool\itp\plugins\com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy\runtime\ejbmapvalidate.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\derby\lib\derby.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\sib.api.jmsra.rar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.mq.connector.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.mq.headers.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.mq.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.mq.jms.admin.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.mqjms.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.msg.client.jms.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.msg.client.matchspace.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.msg.client.provider.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.msg.client.ref.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors\wmq.jmsra.rar\dhbcore.jar;G:\db2jccdriver\db2jcc.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\universalDriver\lib\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;G:\db2jccdriver\db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar;G:\mssqldriver\sqljdbc_3.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/properties;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/properties;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/startup.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar;G:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar;G:\Projects\POC\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\ssopocWAR\WEB-INF\classes;G:\Projects\POC\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\ssopocWAR\WEB-INF\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;G:\Projects\POC\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\ssopocWAR\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;G:\Projects\POC\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\ssopocWAR\WEB-INF\lib\jsp-api-2.0.jar;G:\Projects\POC\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\ssopocWAR\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar;G:\Projects\POC\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\ssopocWAR\WEB-INF\lib\spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;G:\Projects\POC\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\ssopocWAR\WEB-INF\lib\spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;G:\Projects\POC\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\ssopocWAR\WEB-INF\lib\spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;G:\Projects\POC\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\ssopocWAR\WEB-INF\lib\spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;G:\Projects\POC\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\ssopocWAR\WEB-INF\lib\spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;G:\Projects\POC\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\ssopocWAR\WEB-INF\lib\spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;G:\Projects\POC\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\ssopocWAR]

Comment: Any chance of getting a stacktrace? It sounds like WebSphere is printing this for a `NoClassDefFoundError` or a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: I am also getting similar issue, any resolution for the above isssue!!!